# Array that's supposed to store JSON is empty after successful JSON parsing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
 var pokemons = [Pokemon]()

    func loadJSON() {
        let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
        guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let pokedex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokedex.self, from: data)

                for pokemon in pokedex.results {
                    guard let jsonURL = pokemon.url else { return }
                    guard let newURL = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newURL) {(data, response, error) in
                        guard let data = data else { return }

                        do {
                            let load = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokemon.self, from: data)
                            self.pokemons.append(load)

                        } catch let jsonErr {
                            print("Error serializing inner JSON:", jsonErr)
                        }
                    }.resume()
                }
            } catch let jsonErr{
                print("Error serializing JSON: ", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

This code compiles and runs fine, but the array pokemons returns a count of 0 when I check its size afterwards. It's strange because if I loop through the array right after the pokemons.append(load), it'll spit out a bunch of data. It's as if the data gets lost as soon as it's out of scope of the JSON. Does my array need to be passed by reference or something? I'm looking to take the data and put it into a UITableView, but so far nothing is showing.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Pokemon"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        loadJSON()
        print(pokemons.count) //Prints 0
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "By Id"
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return label
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pokemons.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        let name = pokemons[indexPath.row].name

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(name) Section:\(indexPath.section) Row:\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `loadJSON` is asynchronous.

Comment: hey! sorry I'm not familiar with what that means. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need

```
self.pokemons.append(load)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or write a completion

---

the asynchronous call is something that doesn't go in serial with function  written code , but runs asynchronously until it finishes then it notifies it's callback and in your code the asynchronous method is `URLSession.shared.dataTask` which runs in a background thread (that's why you have to insert `DispatchQueue.main.async` inside it to refresh the UI ) and leave the serial execution at main thread for sure you can block the main thread until response returns with a method like `Data(contentsOf:url)` instead of `URLSession.shared.dataTask` but it's not a good idea

Comment: thanks for you answer! I'm still not really understanding why that's important. Could you explain!